# Failed review audit by voting to close

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/28125173) by voting to close. The comments on the question also suggested that some believes that the question is off-topic, and even some answers say the question is likely closed. The question is not programming-related and is very broad. Any chance that my failed audit can be voided?

Comment: Answers that start like this frustrate me sometimes me:*"It's very likely this question is going to be closed. Anyway, I'm going to answer it"* If you *know* it's going to be closed, why answer? >_<

Comment: The question received downvotes and is likely going to be closed in a minute, thus it will be removed from the audit pool. Regarding the audit failure, there is nothing to worry about if it's an isolated incident.

Comment: This was a bad audit, plain and simple. You were fully correct in voting to close that question. Fortunately, you were not suspended as a result, and the content has already been dealt with outside of the review queues, so there is nothing left to be done here. Sorry about the frustration; bad audits suck. I wish we could do something better about these, but unfortunately they're chosen entirely by machine and moderators have no specific ability to curate the list of audits or change history.

Comment: Sounds like there needs to be an audit review queue.  Only question is will the audit review queue itself have an audit?